# How to disable effects of .htaccess within a subfolder if there is a .htaccess file in root?

Tags: .htaccess

In my application I have separate spaces for user and admin like 
if `www.example.com` is my website, then `www.example.com/admin` is my admin URL.

I am using a .htaccess file in my root, and it affects some of the functionality in my admin folder, which I don't want to.

For example, consider below is my folder structure

```
..
.htaccess
index.php
admin
```

So if I don't want the .htaccess rules to apply within the admin folder, is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people that don't have direct access to httpd.conf (shared hosting for example), just put another .htaccess file in the subfolder and set to the desired behavior.

Comment: This approach seems not to work. The CSP directives of the root are considered, even if you put another htaccess inside the subfolder. I guess you need to do the changes in the root's .htaccess with `<Directory "/path/to/subfolder"> ... </Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, but it does require write access to the httpd.conf configuration.

If you have access to the httpd.conf file, something like

```
    <Directory /admin>
      AllowOverride None
    </Directory
```

should do the trick.

Also, note that using .htaccess files in the root directory (as you said you did) is not a recommended approach. You'd be better off moving the contents of the htaccess file into the proper contexts of the httpd.conf file.

More information can be found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride